# Thumbnail in jQuery Mobile Collapsible Listview

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

Is there any way to create jQM Collapsible Listview with thumbnail (not icon).

Example: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html

Not Icon like this: [How can I create a collapsible list with thumbnails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101008/how-can-i-create-a-collapsible-list-with-thumbnails)

I tried insert 'img' tag into the 'li' as normal listview way (non-collapsible listview), but the image doesn't display.

So is it possible to insert thumbnail? Please advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the img tag works fine within a collapsible:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
     <h4>Some Animals</h4>
     <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/animals/1/" />
              <h2>Rhinos</h2>
              <p>Description of pic 1</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#">
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/animals/2/" />
             <h2>Ape</h2>
             <p>Description of pic 2</p>
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#">
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/animals/3/" />
             <h2>Tiger</h2>
             <p>Description of pic 4</p>
           </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/s4y7S/)**

Comment: Hi, what I mean is, I need the thumbnail to be in first level. In your example, the thumbnail need to added to 'Some Animals'. Not its content. I don't have problem with adding thumbnail to its listview content.

Comment: Ya, something like that. So jQM default do not support that is it?

Comment: @MarkZ, correct, jQM does not support this by default.

Comment: Alright thanks. Then I'll add in additional custom CSS to make it work. Thanks.